# Что делает следующая строчка в коде?

Tags: c

Что делает первая строчка в While - " reverse = reverse * 10;" Если reverse = 0 , а оно еще потом его и умножает. (Задача на палиндром)

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  main()
  {
  int n, reverse = 0, temp;

printf_s("4islo\n");
scanf_s("%d", &n);

temp = n;

while (temp != 0)
{
    reverse = reverse * 10; // Что делает эта строчка?
    reverse = reverse + temp % 10;
    temp = temp / 10;
}

if (n == reverse)
    printf_s("%d da\n", n);
else
    printf_s("%d net\n", n);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Она равна 0 только при первой итерации. Мой совет — возьмите бумажку, и карандашиком прогоните какие-нибудь вычисления, с каким-то 12345... Вам сразу станет все куда понятнее.

Comment: Наверное  было бы понятней, если заменить тут 2 строки на одну `reverse = reverse * 10 + temp % 10;`

Answer (score 3):

```
reverse = reverse * 10;
```

Все верно, на первой итерации цикла переменная `reverse` равна нулю, потом:

```
reverse = reverse + temp % 10;
```

присваивает переменной  `reverse` значение, и уже на второй итерации переменная `reverse` не равна нулю.